# Heat Recovery Systems for cooling - how good are they?

Tags: hvac, cooling

I live in a flat in the UK where it gets quite hot indoors and outdoors for some of the year, though rarely above 35c outdoors.

I currently have a nuaire HVAC system installed, with all the ducting, and i've recently come across a new product which claims that it can use the existing hvac system and add cooling capacity (https://www.nuaire.co.uk/product-list-page/mrxbox-hybrid-cooling-system)

Does anyone have experience with these kinds of systems? It seems like an interesting idea, and I don't think I can install an AC unit in my flat as an alternative.

Comment: Energy recovery systems (which transfer humidity as well as heat between airstreams usually work better for air conditioning ventilation heat exchange, as dehumidification is a large part of what cooling the air does. In any case the two functions may be packaged as one unit in this case, but the functions are separate - an HRV or ERV will make incoming fresh air closer to the temperature of the inside, but the cooling unit part of the system will be what makes the inside air cooler. The web page linked is **very vague indeed** about details of the system.

Comment: Humidification is tightly linked to heating actually, because humidity affects **our sense of** temperature.  And hot air holds more water than cold air.  That means you must be very careful with air-path routing in air conditioners,  so you keep inside air inside and outside air outside (not like 1-hose portable A/Cs).  It's also important to manage draughts.  If outside air is coming in, it's hot **and humid**.